# Fatty acids into glucose

Tags: fat-metabolism, glucose

I have a question regarding the synthesis of glucose from fatty acids. In my book as well as in other posts on stackexchange, it states that fatty acids CANNOT be turned into glucose for the following reason:
Fatty acids are converted into acetyl-CoA, which cannot be reverted into pyruvate because humans do not have the enzyme, but some plants do. Therefore, fatty acids cannot be turned into glucose.
Glycerol however can be converted into glucose by gluconeogenesis.

However, fatty acids can be turned into acetone by ketogenesis and acetones CAN be converted into pyruvate and therefore also into glucose. So doesn't that mean that fatty acids can be turned into glucose?
Fatty acid -> acetyl-CoA -> acetone -> pyruvate -> glucose.

Ketogenesis happens during a carbohydrate deficiency (or diabetes mellitus). The brain is able to use ketones for energy, but preferably uses glucose, so I'd assume some ketones are converted to glucose as well?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered on this site. Please search previous questions. If you have a hypothesis about a reaction sequence, write out the reactions in full. That way you will discover the fallacy of your argument yourself. Arrows between compounds don’t cut it.

Comment: As stated in the original comment, I have looked at other posts on Stackexchange and I have also presented the answers that I found. Yet I haven't seen anyone say anything about the conversion of fatty acids into glucose via acetone. 

@user1136: It isn't really about net synthesis of glucose, the question is: are fatty acids able to be converted into glucose? If acetone can be converted into glucose and fatty acids into acetone, then isn't the conclusion that fatty acids can be converted into glucose via ketogenesis? I am not talking about fatty acids into to acetyl-CoA to glucose

Comment: Fatty acid chains are used to form acetyl-CoA molecules. Two acetyl-CoA molecules condense to form 1 molecule of acetoacetic acid. Part of acetoacetic molecules are converted into acetone & beta-hydroxybutyrate.

If fatty acids can be converted into glucose, then isn't the book and the posts wrong? They state that fatty acids can't be converted into glucose because acetyl-CoA into pyruvate isn't possible, but the conversion via acetone should be possible?

Comment: I don't know the exact chemistry behind it, but when I look up reactions of the conversion I find the following: acetone -> acetol -> methylgloxal -> pyruvate -> glucose, so maybe this explains how acetone is converted into pyruvate?

Comment: I don't believe that there is significant conversion of ketone bodies to glucose in starvation. There is no evidence that the methylglyoxal pathway is used in normal animals, and indeed methylglyoxal is highly toxic. Experiments in 1984 feeding rats with high concentrations of acetone (which is only produced from ketone bodies by non-enzymic reactions) fail to convince.